# Is there a function that can help me to select a closest value to the specific value from the row?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have pandas dataframe and the first 4 columns are related to country information and the other columns are the number of passengers divided according to year. I have only one row and I am trying to get the closest value to that of 2020. It goes until 2020.

| Country Name | Country Code | 1960 | 1961 | 1961 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| European Union | EUU | NaN | 1.392831e+7 | 1.519181e+7 |

Comment: Can you narrow down this problem? What columns and rows are you talking about? An excel spreadsheet, a pandas dataframe, a csv file, ...?

Comment: Sure , I use pandas dataframe. @CoryKramer

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data

Comment: I put NaN for the year 1960 but it goes until 2020 and values are not always NaN. I hope it is sufficient. I did not know how to share the sample of the data. Many thanks. @mozway

Comment: Can you provide a few more/rows columns? And the expected output. It is directly currently too ambiguous to know what you want